# Storing object implementing a generic interface in a collection

Tags: c#, .net

I have a number of classes that are all implementing `IWidget<T>` interface. I would like to add them to a list, so I define something like this:

```
List<IWidget<T>> _widgetList;
```

Here the compiler complains about the T is not being recognized:

> Error 1  The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there a way to define a list of IWidget and still keep the generic interface?

I am using .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: You mean List<IWidget<T>> _widgetList; ?

Comment: Is your `IWidget` itself a generic interface (that is, is it defined as `public interface IWidget<T> { }`) and if so, does it inherit from a non-generic `IWidget`?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yes, IWidget is a generic interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There are a few ways you can go about doing this:

**1)** you need a non-generic root:

```
public interface IWidget
{
      ...
}

public interface IWidget<T> : IWidget
{
      ...
}
```

so that you can use `List<IWidget> _widgetList;`

---

**2)** you can use `dynamic`s or polymorphism with contra/co-variance, but you will have to play by the rules the rules it has, **`<T>` mustn't be a value type** and you'll have to cast after accessing but not when adding, like this:

```
IWidget<string> xxx = ...;

var widgetListDyn = new List<IWidget<dynamic>>();
var widgetListObj = new List<IWidget<object>>();

widgetListDyn.Add(xxx);
widgetListObj.Add(xxx);
```

---

**3)** or you can mix the two approaches:

```
public interface IWidget : IWidget<object> {}
```

and you can use `List<IWidget> _widgetList;` with this technique also you'll also need a cast before a `.add()`:

```
List<IWidget> _widgetList = new List<IWidget>();
IWidget<string> xxx = ...;
IWidget xxx1 = (IWidget)xxx;

_widgetList.Add(xxx1);
```

---

**4)** one last way you could go about it is:

```
public class IWidgetList<T> : List<IWidget<T>> { }
```

which would be useful if you plan to have a declare a lot of the lists created in keeps you from the ugly syntax of: `List<IWidget<TYPE>>` and instead you can just use: `IWidgetList<TYPE>` and it is identical

Answer (score 2):

You need to use either a non generic root interface:

```
public interface IWidget<T> : IWidget
{
}
```

or specify the type at the point of declaration:

```
List<IWidget<MyType>> widgetList;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is your IWidget interface generic, i.e. is it actually IWidget<T>? Or just IWidget?

If it's not a generic interface, you just want the following:

```
public class ContainingClass
{
   List<IWidget> _widgetList;
}
```

If it is a generic interface, then what you need is something like this:

```
public class ContainingClass<T> where T : class // or some other constraint for T
{
   List<IWidget<T>> _widgetList;
}
```

Comment: It is a generic interface. IWidget<T>. Sorry for the confusion